# Combining two sub routines without re-selecting file

Tags: vba, excel

I have written two sub routines which are both currently assigned to separate buttons in the main template workbook. They both work without errors and all is good but I would like to be able to combine them so that one button will execute the whole routine in one. Now I know a simple call could work here but that then requires the user to re-select files.

So the first routine creates two appropriately named text files and then second routine removes all the blank rows (white space) that is created when the original text files are created but at the moment, the user is required to re-select the newly generated text file to execute.

Is there a good, effective way to combine these without losing functionality? Without just calling the second routine?

```
     Option Explicit

     Public Sub OneRoutine()

     Dim strFile As String
     Dim MyNewBook As String
     Dim MySaveFile As String
     Dim fileToOpen As Variant
     Dim fileName As String
     Dim sheetName As String
     Dim rCopy As Range
     Dim lastrow As Integer
     Dim wb As Workbook


     'Turn off display alerts
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     'Turn off screen updates
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     'Ensures that the file open directory is always the same
     ChDir "S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment Limited\"

     'Opens the folder to location to select txt file
     fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
        If fileToOpen <> False Then
        Workbooks.OpenText fileName:=fileToOpen, _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
        End If
     'Creates the file name based on txt file name
    fileName = Mid(fileToOpen, InStrRev(fileToOpen, "\") + 1)
    'Creates the sheet name based on the active txt file
    sheetName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4)

    'Rename the original text file
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment Limited\" 
     & "DNU_" & fileName)

    'Save active file as...
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment 
     Limited\BACS File Original\" & _
    fileName & ".CSV"), FileFormat:=xlCSV

    'Selects all data in column A and copies to clipboard
    Set rCopy = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))

     'Open the original document where the BACS file is located
    Workbooks.Open "S:\Accounts (New)\Management Information (Analysis)\Phil 
     Hanmore - Analysis\bacs conversion calc.xlsx"
    'Selects the worksheet called "Original"
    Sheets("Original").Range("A:A").ClearContents

    'Paste selected values from previous sheet
    rCopy.Copy
    Sheets("Original").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    'This checks cells T5 and U5 on the "Original" tab. If either are false 
     then the macro will stop, if both are true it will continue on normally
     If Range("T5").Value = "False" Then
       MsgBox "An error has occured!" & vbNewLine & "Please speak to Phil 
    Hanson before continuing", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Range("U5").Value = "False" Then
       MsgBox "An error has occured!" & vbNewLine & "Please speak to Phil 
     Hanson before continuing", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Saves the BACS Conversion Calculator
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "S:\Accounts (New)\Management Information 
      (Analysis)\Phil Hanmore - Analysis\bacs conversion calc.xlsx"

     'Selects appropriate worksheet - Non-MyPayFINAL
     Sheets("Non-MyPay FINAL").Select

    'Selects all data in column A and copies to clipboard
    Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    'Add a new workbook
    Workbooks.Add
    'Paste selected values from previous sheet
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


    'Build SaveAs file name (for CSV file)
    MySaveFile = Format(Now(), "DDMMYYYY") & "NonMyPayFINALTest" & ".CSV"
    'Save template file as...(for CSV file)
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment Limited\" 
     & MySaveFile), FileFormat:=xlCSV

     'Build SaveAs file name (for Txt file)
    MySaveFile = Format(Now(), "DDMMYYYY") & "NonMyPayFINALTest" & ".Txt"
    strFile = "S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment Limited\" & MySaveFile
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (strFile), FileFormat:=xlTextWindows
    'Save template file as...(for Txt file)
    'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment 
    Limited\" & MySaveFile), FileFormat:=xlTextWindows

    'Close the new saved file
     ActiveWorkbook.Close

     Call AltText_V2



    'Selects appropriate worksheet - MyPayFINAL
    Sheets("MyPay FINAL").Select

    'Selects all data in column A and copies to clipboard
    Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    'Add a new workbook
    Workbooks.Add
    'Paste selected values from previous sheet
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    'Build SaveAs file name (for CSV file)
    MySaveFile = Format(Now(), "DDMMYYYY") & "MyPayFINALTest" & ".CSV"
    'Save template file as...(for CSV file)
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment Limited\" 
     & MySaveFile), FileFormat:=xlCSV

    'Build SaveAs file name (for Txt file)
    MySaveFile = Format(Now(), "DDMMYYYY") & "MyPayFINALTest" & ".Txt"
    strFile = "S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment Limited\" & MySaveFile
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (strFile), FileFormat:=xlTextWindows
    'Close the new saved file
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    'Save template file as...(for Txt file)
    'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment 
    Limited\" & MySaveFile), FileFormat:=xlTextWindows
    Call AltText_V2

    'Close original source workbook (template)
    Windows("bacs conversion calc.xlsx").Close
    'Close final workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
      'Deletes the original copy
     Kill fileToOpen
     'Displays message box
      MsgBox "Your file has been processed successfully!", vbExclamation

    'Calls the next subroutine
    'Call AltText_V2

   'Turn on display alerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Turn on screen updates
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

     End Sub

     Sub AltText_V2()
      Dim inFile As String
      Dim outFile As String
      Dim data As String
      Dim strFile As String

     'Ensures that the file open directory is always the same
      ChDir "S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment Limited\"

     'inFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
     inFile = strFile
     Open inFile For Input As #1

     outFile = inFile & ".txt"
     Open outFile For Output As #2

      Do Until EOF(1)
      Line Input #1, data

      If Trim(data) <> "" Then
         Print #2, data
      End If
     Loop

     Close #1
     Close #2

     Kill inFile
     Name outFile As inFile

     MsgBox "File alteration completed!"
     End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, two routines is a better approach, you should simply pass the name of the file from the first routine to the second. Thus, it would work and you do not need for select. If it is one routine, it gets too long and messy. Try something like this:

```
'Option Explicit

Public Sub OneRoutine()
    Dim strFile As String

    '...rest of the code

    MySaveFile = Format(Now(), "DDMMYYYY") & "MyPayFINALTest" & ".Txt"
    strFile = "S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment Limited\" & MySaveFile
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (strFile), FileFormat:=xlTextWindows

    Call AltText_V2(strFile)

    'Close the new saved file
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    '...rest of the code

End Sub

Sub AltText_V2(strFile As String)

    Dim inFile As String
    Dim outFile As String
    Dim data As String

    'Ensures that the file open directory is always the same
    ChDir "S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment Limited\"

    inFile = strFile
    Open inFile For Input As #1

    '...rest of the code

End Sub
```

Furthermore, the second routine becomes a bit more reuseable and independent and thus in general the code is robust.

Comment: This looks really good but I currently get a Path/File access error - runtime 75 on the line "Open inFile For Input As #1" in the second routine? What have I done wrong? Plus, do I repeat the process shown above for Non My Pay final as well? I.e both text files?

Comment: @Dyhouse, then close the file before calling it with the procedure. Thus, you may have to put `Call AltText_V2(strFile)` twice in your code. Make sure that each time time you close the `strFile` properly.

Comment: I have done exactly as suggested but I am getting the same error (path/file access error - runtime 75) on the same line (open infile for input as #1). I will edit my question so you can see the routine as it stands now

Comment: @Dyhouse - when you edit, remove all the useless stuf, and do it really a minimal question - e.g. all the ranges check and etc. Also remove the Paths selection and hardcode them - thus it would be easier to replicate.

Comment: Apologies, I was editing as you messaged, I'm not entirely sure I understand when you say useless stuff? Would you mind editing my code so I have an idea going forward please? Same applies with the path selection....I am pretty new to VBA so I am still learning.

Comment: @Dyhouse - I mean useless like `Set rCopy = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))`, as far as they are not part of the initial problem. In general, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you for that I will do going forward. As it stands though, do you have any idea what is causing my issue?

Comment: @Dyhouse - it can be plenty of things. But most probably, you are passing `strFile` to the procedure that does not exist. Put a `debug.print strFile` before and check whether it exists.

Comment: I can see that the file name is stored in strFile accurately in the initial sub routine but then is blank or (strFile="") when it comes to the second routine which has just been called. I have to admit, I am not sure how to rectify it?

Comment: Do I need to declare the variable strFile differently? I am scouring this site trying to find an answer....

Comment: @Dyhouse - you need to declare it just once, however, you should give values to it two times. Once with the first file and once with the second file.

Comment: I believe that is what I have done though? Am I missing something in the second routine which the stored filename disappears?

Comment: In your code you are calling `Call AltText_V2` without a parameter? You need parameter there. @Dyhouse

Answer (score 0):

You can save filepath to global variable and then don't involve pop-up for select file.